# SSI - актуальность технологии

Tags: html5, include, ssi

Не являюсь ни программистом, ни даже опытным верстальщиком. Уровень владения предметом - html+css+чуть-чуть js

И сейчас решаю такую задачу на статичном сайте (набор хтмл-страниц): **блоки  меню и футер, которые одинаковы на всех страницах, хочу вынести во внешние файлы**.

Знаю, что сейчас используют либо cms, либо шаблонизатор. Но php еще не владею, поэтому шаблонизатор - это пока сложно для меня. Что касается cms, встроенные инструменты не дают возможности настроить всё так, как мне нужно с точки зрения SEO, а менять шаблоны - это опять пхп.

Обнаружила в этой связи **технологию SSI**. Уточнила у хостера, что она поддерживается. Но, вижу в инете, что все мануалы, описания и проч. датированы примерно 2012 годом. Исключение - википедия, там последняя редакция - ноябрь 2018

**Отсюда ВОПРОС: это актуальная технология? Или что-то вроде табличной верстки и инлайновых стилей?**

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSI имеет (и всегда имел) очень ограниченный набор функций, который никогда не должен был конкурировать с реальными языками сценариев. Таким образом, технология живая и хорошая.

<sup>[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651682/is-ssi-still-relevant)</sup>